# How to add a footerText in a grid in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, footer

I have a grid that looks something like this

```
----------------------
Id | Customer | Total
----------------------
100| Foo, Inc.| $19.95
----------------------
200| Bar, LLC.| $23.50
----------------------
```

Lets say there is a lot of data and its scrollable. When I scroll to the end, I need to display some text inside the grid body.

```
----------------------
Id | Customer | Total
----------------------
100| Foo, Inc.| $19.95
----------------------
200| Bar, LLC.| $23.50
----------------------
<my text goes here>
----------------------
```

It should not be a dockedItem. Docked Items are not part of the scrollable region of the grid. How do I achieve this in ExtJS 4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a summary you want to show at the end?

Comment: @Saki Its more like a disclaimer. So the existing Grid summary feature cant be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the `Html` property of the grid to give you inline elements and then just move them around in the dom to the correct place to append underneath your rows.

E.g.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: {
                'items': [{
                    'name': 'Lisa',
                    "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-111-1224"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Bart',
                    "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1234"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Homer',
                    "email": "homer@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1244"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Marge',
                    "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1254"
                }]
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'items'
                }
            }
        });

        var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            // Now add the custom HTML
            html: '<div class="myTest">This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test  This is a test This is a test This is a test  This is a test This is a test This is a test  This is a test This is a test This is a test  This is a test This is a test This is a test </div>',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            scroll: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
        // Select and cache the new content element
        var myContent = Ext.get(Ext.dom.Query.selectNode('.myTest'), /*Optional root*/ myGrid.getEl());

        // Now get the HTML and append into the rows container

        var rowsContainer = myGrid.getEl().select('.x-grid-item-container').elements[0];
        myContent.appendTo(rowsContainer);

    }
});
```

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/g8a

Comment: Thanks Rob. This is what I was looking for. But I am not able to get this to work in ExtJS 4. Any ideas Rob?

Comment: I am getting rowsContainer as undefined. I am doing this in the grid's afterrender event. Also, when I click on the column header, the text moves above the rows.

Comment: I have amended the example for ExtJS 4 https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gaf however there are issues with styling if the rows get longer than the grid height.  I'll leave you to work that out.  You'll also need to re-do some of the work on each `sortchange` event. Look at the docs to guide you http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-html

Comment: That worked perfectly fine. Except that the text appears before the data. By the time the gridContent is getting added to the rowsContainer, there is no other element in it. Anyway to do this after the grid is rendered with the data?

Comment: Using the above code in store.on('load') did the trick. Thanks Rob.